# Hiding balloons on tap on MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I have a MapView with 3 different ItemizedOverlays that act with a similar behavior. They all work alright, but they only respond to taps on the items, they do nothing if I tap the map. Setting a OnClickListener on the MapView has proven to be unresponsive. Is there any way of hiding the balloon when tapping outside of it without losing pinch to zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove balloons in `onTouchEvent` of `ItemizedOverlay` as touch events work for each. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, it works! Have been trying it for over two days! Thank you very much :)